# how to implement multi instance jplayers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

If there is anyone who has used jplayer before, I need help with this question.

I have multiple jplayers where each player is suppose to play its own audio file. But it is not doing this, if I play a jplayer, then all the jplayers play, all playing that one audio file from the selected jplayers. In fact if I use a control in one jplayer, it controls all the other jplayers as well.

So I am trying to implement a multi instance jplayers which information comes from this:

http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-03/

But I am really struggling in able to implement this so my question is can somebody help me finish off the implementation for this so that the jplayers work as it should do and a jplayer just controls its own player only and not affect other jplayers?

Below is the javascript code I have at the moment for this (view source):

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1-72-0").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: "AudioFiles/Kalimba.mp3"
      });
    },
    play: function() { // To avoid both jPlayers playing together.
      $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
   },
    solution:"flash,html",
    swfPath: "jquery",
    supplied: "mp3"
  });
}); 
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

Actual Code:

If there is no audio file, display a blank else for each audio file, display a audio player. I included the html controls as well, not sure if needed but posted it just in case

```
        //start:procedure audio
        $aud_result = '';
        if(empty($arrAudioFile[$key])){
          $aud_result = '&nbsp;';
        }else{

$j = 0;
foreach ($arrAudioFile[$key] as $a) { 

        $info = pathinfo('AudioFiles/'.$a); 
?>

<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function(){

$("#jquery_jplayer_1-<?php echo $key.'-'.$j; ?>").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        <?php echo $info['extension'];?>: "<?php echo "AudioFiles/".$a; ?>"
      });
      $(this).bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function() { 
          $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
        });
    },
    solution:"flash,html",
    swfPath: "jquery",
    supplied: "<?php echo $info['extension'];?>"
});
}); 
</script>
  <div id="jquery_jplayer_1-<?php echo $key.'-'.$j; ?>" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
  <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
    <div class="jp-type-single">
      <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
        <ul class="jp-controls">
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="jp-progress">
          <div class="jp-seek-bar">
            <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-volume-bar">
          <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-time-holder">
          <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
          <div class="jp-duration"></div>
          <ul class="jp-toggles">
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">repeat</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off">repeat off</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php $j++; 
}

}
//end:procedure audio
?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a `function` and pass parameters (`file and player id`) like this to create different players on the same page without any conflict:

```
function js_audioPlayer(file,location) {
    jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_" + location).jPlayer( {
        ready: function () {
          jQuery(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: file
          });
        },
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_interface_" + location,
        swfPath: "/swf"
    });
        return;
}
```

In this example, a file and location variable is passed into a wrapper function, which then constructs the player.

and then run the `js_audioPlayer()` javascript function as many times as you want players:

```
js_audioPlayer('file1.mp3',1); //Player 1
js_audioPlayer('file2.mp3',2); //Player 2
js_audioPlayer('file3.mp3',3); //Player 3
```

creating Player DIVs with IDs:

```
jquery_jplayer_1 
jquery_jplayer_2
jquery_jplayer_3
```

and Interface DIVs with IDs:

```
jp_interface_1
jp_interface_2
jp_interface_3
```

Hope this helps.

**For more detail**: http://www.nightbluefruit.com/blog/2011/08/multiple-jplayers-on-the-same-page/

Comment: Good answer, but it's not technically accurate to say that this dynamically creates the divs; rather, it dynamically creates the jPlayer instances from the existing divs in your HTML. Dynamically creating the divs based on a template would be possible, of course.

Comment: @AlphaMale I am struggling to implement this in my actual code, in my actual code it comes in a for each loop where it uses a bit of a php, can I show you an update showing my actual code (as I showed view source code) and can you do me a huge favour and include in your answer how this can be implemented for my actual code? It is a big favour I am asking but really appreciate it if you can do this for me

Comment: @AlphaMale I posted actual code, I do not know if you want to see the code for the html jplayer controls, if you don't want to see this then I will remove it

Comment: @user2056342 Do share how you did that... :)

Answer (score 0):

This is code for multiple instance of audio player using jplayer.
Following code is working for me. Hope this helps anyone.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*---Create a jplayer instance on click on the play image---*/

    $(".audio").click(function() {
       $.jPlayer.pause();
       var record_id = this.id;
       var path = 'path for the audio file';
       $("#jquery_jplayer_"+record_id).jPlayer({
            ready: function (event) {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    title: "Bubble",
                    oga: path,
                });
            },
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_"+record_id,
            supplied: "oga",
            wmode: "window",
            errorAlerts: true,
            consoleAlerts: true,
            warningAlerts: true,
            useStateClassSkin: true,
            autoBlur: false,
            smoothPlayBar: true,
            keyEnabled: true,
            remainingDuration: true,
            toggleDuration: true
        });
    });
});
```